# how to make textbox who only allow integer value?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to make a textbox in my wpf application which will accept only integer values. if someone types characters between [a-z], the textbox will reject it. Thus it will not be displayed in the textbox

Comment: I think this type of question has been asked before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346707/validation-in-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: Why dont yoy use DataValidation in WPF which is built exactly for this kind of things? http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataValidation.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle the PreviewTextInput event:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  // Filter out non-digit text input
  foreach (char c in e.Text) 
    if (!Char.IsDigit(c)) 
    {
      e.Handled = true;
      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add handle of the `TextChanged` event and look what was entered (need to check all text every time for preventing pasting letters from clipboard).

Also look a very good example of creating maskable editbox on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MaskableTextBox.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you can handle the `KeyDown` event like this:

```
private void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This will only prevent from entering text, but not from paste from clipboard.

Comment: copy/paste will always require a special tratment with post validation anyway, but the idea of doing a prefilter is probably better in this case. It can then be coupled with a post-validation. I would rather use the PreviewTextInput event instead of the KeyDOwn event though

Answer (score 1):

this simple code snippet should do the trick.. You might also want to check for overflows (too large numbers)

```
private void IntegerTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
    {
        int c = Text[i];
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
        {
           Text = Text.Remove(i, 1);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not prevent the user to type a "non-integer", it just removes it when it has been typed. Jogy's solution using the previewTextInput methods seems better. Your solution could be used as a post validation though (case of copy/paste)

Comment: Yes you are right, sometimes you can see "flickering" where the text appears and then disappears when this code is used. I guess the best solution is a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

Bind it to Integer property. WPF will do the validation itself without any extra hassle.